# Magento 2 Configuration settings - Clarify app:config:dump vs app:config:import

Tags: magento2, configuration, core-config-data

I just want to understand the workflow of Magento 2 configuration settings.

### Intro

In Magento 2, there are these command-line commands:
`app:config:dump`
`app:config:import`

### Questions

Am I correct in saying:

- `app:config:dump` is for *importing from database into configuration file (app/etc/config.php)*.
- `app:config:import` is for *importing from configuration file (app/etc/config.php) into the database.*
- Assuming this is correct, would I only really use the configuration file when importing data into a **new database from existing settings in a config.php file (ie run `app:config:import` once**, then change everything I need in the admin backend instead of in config.php file (ie site specific styling etc).
- After I am done with everything (so last step), I run `app:config:dump`, to update the config.php file again?
- Somewhere along the way all my settings became locked in the M2 backend, I assume it is because I ran `app:config:dump`?  (I figured out clearing specific entries from config.php json they will be editable again, and saved to database).

This workflow of locked configuration settings in backend is really inefficient so I decided to clear everything in config.php file (instead of the modules enable/disable) settings.

Can someone please clarify these for me please.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been fighting with the Magento deployment workflow and configuration properties for a while

## LESSONS LEARNED

**1. It can be painful!**

`app:config:dump` creates the `env.php` and `config.php` files dumping all the database config in them. They then "lock" these fields in the admin

A change to `env.php` or `config.php` files will instantly create an error 500 until it is read into the database. So put maintenance before you change things.

For one little change use the command line instead. (more later)

**2. `app:config:import`  first wipes all settings in the database**

if a setting is not in the files, that particular option will be back to default. (whereas in #3 they are left as is)

I didn't expect that the first time!

The idea is that it is for a deployment in a stable deployment workflow where you clone everything eg deploying containers at installation

**3. `setup:upgrade` will update settings from file only**

Settings not in the file will be left as they are (whereas in #2 they are reset to default)

This allows you to set some settings locked in file while leaving others editable in admin.

BUT: running setup:upgrade it also clears generated files and caches, so you have to compile and deploy static again each time, not great if you just want to change a few small settings. (But in a magento workflow you can just copy the compiled and static files over from the build machine orrepository again which is quick)

UPDATE: @john-hall reports quite rightly that `setup:upgrade --keep-generated`  will preserve the generated files to minimise disruption

**4. config:set (saves to env or config) and config:sensitive:set (saves to environment) are the least disruptive way to change things**

They update both the file and the database.

They do not wipe cache, generated files or anything - as a matter of fact for some things you might have to clear config cache manually to see an effect.

It can be complicated to figure out the path and options but but it beats having to go either of the previous two ways

eg: `bin/magento --scope=store --scope-code=default config:set web/unsecure/base_url`
 `bin/magento config:set -c msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_login 0`

There is a ridiculously long list to figure out, name wise, so I do

`bin/magento config:show > configlist`

so i have a file i can search through.

**5. anything in these files is locked in admin**

You can lock easily from command line or by putting it in the file and then importing/upgrading

**6. the only unlock is remove-from-file and 'setup:upgrade'**

there is no way to "unlock" via bin/magento config:set that I could find. There really should be.
You have to leave it out of the files and then it will get unlocked. Note that you can then change it in admin, but you can't use config:import then

## To use in a deployment/rollout system

Note: I am still not 100% there

A bit of work needs to be done on this approach because a lot of modules are sloppy and write into the config file settings which could be different from instance to instance, for example different between the dev, build and production instances. Theoretically they can mark variables in the module xml definition as "env" versus "config" or mark them as sensitive, but they don't.

**1. sensitive settings go in environment variable, or env.php**

these are not put into source control. I've stuck with env.php for now

**2. setting that are going to be the same between all stay in config.php**

This can be put in source control and copied from machine to machine.

I am using a partial config.php that leaves "open" things i want to allow changing from the admin interface so I have to use setup:upgrade not the config import. But then often this is rolled out with other changes so that would run anyway.

**3. Things that are machine/environment specific go in env.php**

You can move entire config sections out of config.php into env.php so that you have one env.php per machine/instance and a shared config.php

So whether something is in test mode or not, alternative email addresses etc.

This is one that will take time to decide.

I hope this helps

I have spent quite a few hours comparing, merging and producing my config.php and env.php that lock everything I want to speed up but leaves open things we want to be able to modify. It's not there yet, and just today I wiped entire sections trying to make something editable in admin again...

Comment: this is awesome stuff - how come this had no upvotes yet? thank you!

Comment: thanks @bayer glad it helped. too many things have to be learned the hard way on M2!

Comment: My apologies, to be honest stackexchange website never notified me that this question has received an update!  I am busy reviewing all my questions, and this is most definitely useful.  `app:config:dump` is the opposite of `app:config:import` as I originally suspected - it updates your `config.php` file.

Comment: you're right @CvRChameleon I didnt say anything about the dump part - just the config file/database storage and what is / isnt locked.
And once you do `app:config:dump` everything in it will be locked to file version unless you remove the entries from file and do setup:upgrade

Comment: I am back to this again - I think previous versions of Magento 2 ~ (2.3.1 maybe) imported `app:config:import` _system_ section settings into the database.  I now have around 3500 lines of _system array entries_ inside the config.php file. Its annoying that they decided to not import this section into the database anymore :(

Comment: This is very helpful, +1 from me! You mention (accurately) that `setup:upgrade` will wipe out generated/DI data, however there exists a flag for this command `--keep-generated` which skips this step. This is a crucial step in our deployment process wherein after copying the RC from build to production, the exit codes from `app:config:status` and `setup:db:status` are evaluated to determine if the RC contains config or schema changes. If so, I execute `setup:upgrade --keep-generated` (a few seconds of downtime; enable maintenance first) to apply these changes. Exporting configs is still a PITA!

Comment: @iphigenie, are you sure you are correct with `setup:upgrade` only updating settings that are in the file?  I have just tried deleting everything in config.php except for modules array, ran `setup:upgrade` and it has changed all the db settings back to default.  Running M2.4.1.

Is there a way to clear to the config.php without clearing the settings?

Comment: Hi Tim - I'm pretty sure I have never had things overridden that weren't in the file. I regularly empty it of all except modules and it's fine.
The database settings are in env.php so if that file was still there that might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

open config.php file from app/etc/config.php location.

Now remove everything from this file except - modules array like below code :

```
return array (
'modules' => 
array (
'Magento_Store' => 1,
'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
```

then save this file  !!

now after saving this file you need to run below command :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then logged in to your backend admin panel - and check now configuration are unlocked and able to editable.

Comment: This only confirms my last statement : **so I decided to clear everything in config.php file (instead of the modules enable/disable) settings.**    Don't I lose all the settings that are only in the settings file (not in DB) if I delete entries as you suggest?

Comment: This unfortunately does not clarify anything about the rest of my questions - the workflow of the configuration, which is part of this question.